# jQuery AJAX call to WCF service with custom principal

Tags: jquery, ajax, wcf, rest, soap

I have successfully created a WCF service using the webHttpBinding with no authentication or security.  I can call my function over and over and it returns the value as expected.

Now I created a custom IAuthorizationPolicy, UserNamePasswordValidator and IPrincipal.  I went back to wsHttpBinding (default) and did a normal service reference in code and set the ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName and ClientCredentials.UserName.Password appropriately and the service works perfectly fine.  I modified the Username to be wrong just to ensure the code was firing and sure enough it failed.

So, I put the binding back to webHttpBinding, but now I cannot figure out how to set those credentials via jQuery.  I have tried setting the "Authorization" header to a base64 encoded string using the following [How can I pass windows authentication to webservice using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002179/how-can-i-pass-windows-authentication-to-webservice-using-jquery).  No matter what i do i always get the error "No custom principal is specified in the authorization context".

Anyone have info on how to properly call a WCF REST service that is using a Custom Principal?

Answer (score 1):

I was tryng to do something that is not possible.  I have to use the standard HTTP Authentication method because I am working with a REST webservice and not a wsHttpBinding webservice which has alot more wrapped around it.  I found my answer here:

http://www.leastprivilege.com/FinallyUsernamesOverTransportAuthenticationInWCF.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
var html = $.ajax({
  url: "some.jsp",
  username: "sdsdsdsdsd",
  passsword: "xxxxxxxx"
 }).responseText;
```

have tried just passing in the username and password

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: No still get the same error.  Apparently, WCF requires some kind of extra headers set or something along those lines that contains the information needed for a principal.