# .net webservice, jquery ajax, and webservice password question

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, security

I am making a webservice call that needs and authentication password using jquery ajax.  My question is how/where to I store the webservice authentication password so that javascript can use it in the service call in a way that can't be seen from the html code view which would compromise security? Thax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How can I pass windows authentication to webservice using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002179/how-can-i-pass-windows-authentication-to-webservice-using-jquery)

Let me know if that is helpful