# MVC + Ajax call to Controller Loses Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, windows-authentication, http-status-code-401

I've seen similar issues in some posts but none of the answers have helped yet.
My MVC app has a few AJAX/JSON response methods in one controller, and the calls get to destination but it doesn't work in IE or Chrome, and in mozilla it does, but Firebug returns a very strange set of 3 attempts (all return 401 error) but the last one does actually  work!

My App has windows authentication, how can I extend this to my Ajax methods? the rest of the app works fine. I've tried bypassing the 401 by returning 200 Status from Global.asax (Application_EndRequest) but continues to do the same.
Basically all of my Ajax methods have the same problem.

[Here's an image from my firebug console.](http://twitpic.com/4046c6/full)

Comment: Did you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002179/how-can-i-pass-windows-authentication-to-webservice-using-jquery

Comment: I'll give it a try, but really... there's no actual workaround for this? I have another method that isn't even a JsonResult, it just receives POST variables and inserts them into the DB. That one doesn't even work. I get the three 401's in the firebug, but all red (error, no response).

Comment: 401 unauthorized means that access to the URL resource requires user authentication.... read more hear... sorry can't help you more... http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E401.html

Comment: yep but this only happens with ajax calls, the rest of the MVC calls between View and Controller works great...