# HttpHandler and Authentication on jQuery Ajax Call

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication, httphandler

I have an IHttpHandler which I'm running on an Windows Server 2008R2, and IIS 7.5 with integrated mode. The handler should handle file uploads, triggered by a jQuery-Ajax call.

First It did not work on IIS at all, only in the VS 2010 Debugger. Somehow I did manage to register the Handler correctly and I was able to debug the HttpHandler - BUT: Asp.Net Authentication wasn't working: it always said I wasn't logged in. When I directly access the HttpHandler it all works like a charm. Only the jQuery-Ajax call drops dead.

For further information: I'm using FormsAuthentication and it all is running inside an MVC 3 Application.

Could it be related to a missing AuthCookie? I've also read this Article, but it doesn't seem to help me out: [MVC + Ajax call to Controller Loses Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004765/mvc-ajax-call-to-controller-loses-authentication)

If you need any further information / code, just ask for it, I'll post it asap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could it be related to a missing AuthCookie?

Yes, it could, especially if your file upload component uses Flash it might not send the authentication cookie. You may take a look at the [following article](http://zootfroot.blogspot.com/2010/12/mvc-file-upload-using-uploadify-with.html) for a sample workaround which consists into sending the authentication cookie value in addition to the file in the request.

Comment: Okay that seems to have solved the issue. Thank you very much!