# NTLM authentication in Cordova

Tags: ionic-framework, active-directory, cordova-plugins, ntlm, ngcordova

I have to authenticate to a NTLM service but I cannot authenticate from JavaScript. Any solution? I must develop a custom plug in?

Comment: please share your codes here.

Answer (score 0):

A quick research shows that in order to utilize Javascript authentication to NTLM, you'll need a plug-in. See this thread:  [Authenticate Windows Authentication using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6748050/authenticate-windows-authentication-using-javascript)

Note: NTLM has long been deprecated by Microsoft.  Suggest using Kerberos instead. For new questions regarding that usage, open a new question using [kerberos](/questions/tagged/kerberos) and [active-directory](/questions/tagged/active-directory) tags.