# Accessing a WCF in Windows Service by supplying credentials of user accessing the website

Tags: jquery, wcf, windows-services, dynamics-crm-2011, impersonation

i have a Windows Service which hosts a WCF.
I have a CRM application which contains an entity in which i have written a javascript code.
This javascript code calls my WCF using JQuery.

I want that this javascript should be able to pass to WCF, the account of the user who is logged inside CRM. So that the actions that the WCF service does is done under the name of that CRM user.

How should i do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I pass windows authentication to webservice using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002179/how-can-i-pass-windows-authentication-to-webservice-using-jquery)

Comment: no.. it is not a duplicate.. the given link asks for providing user name and password from the ajax call.. i cannot do so..

i want to just pass on the credentials that my page is logged in with..