# How to pass windows authentication to IIS server using jquery ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, authentication, iis

I have an IIS site on a server which runs an ajax call to download information from another IIS site on another server. This brings up a CORS error, but I fixed that by having it allow the server making the call in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the server getting hit. Also enabled windows authentication.

But now, when I make the ajax call, it comes back as authentication denied. I think this is because when I make an ajax call, it is not passing my windows authentication, but just making it anonymously. So when it hits the server, it doesn't know its me. I Also don't want to enable anonymous authentication on the server being hit.

So is there a general way to pass your current windows authentication in jquery ajax when making a call?

Thanks

Comment: this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002179/how-can-i-pass-windows-authentication-to-webservice-using-jquery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I pass windows authentication to webservice using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002179/how-can-i-pass-windows-authentication-to-webservice-using-jquery)