# 401 Unauthorized error when making ajax call to asp.net web api endpoint with window authentication enabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, iis, asp.net-web-api, iis-8.5

I created a simple ASP.NET web api application. I enabled CORS on it using `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors` package.

This is how my controller looks:

```
public class UserController : ApiController
    {
        [Route("user/name")]
        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetUserName()
        {
            dynamic data = new ExpandoObject();
            data.user = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
            var response = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);

            var msg = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Content = new StringContent(response)
            };

            return msg;
        }
    }
```

I am only returning the userid from this controller.

I have hosted the app on IIS 8.5. I have disabled anonymous authentication & enabled windows authentication.

**If I use rest client or directly access the endpoint by entering URL in browser, I get the user name. If I use a REST client, I get the response**

***but if I make AJAX call using jquery, I get 401 status code.***

```
$.ajax({url: 'http://serverName:8899/user/name',   method: 'GET' , 
success:function(res){
alert('hello');
}}) ;
```

**The above call works in IE only chrome gives 401 error**

How can I fix this error. I am enabling windows authentication using IIS and I have not changed my web.config at all. If this is authentication issue, why I am able to retrieve data when I use rest client?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I pass windows authentication to webservice using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002179/how-can-i-pass-windows-authentication-to-webservice-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you also **register CORS support** either Globally, at the Controller, or at the Action.

***Global -***
In your **WebApiConfig.cs** file from **App_Start** folder add:

`public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{`

`// New code:
   var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute(
      origins: "*",
      headers: "*", 
      methods: "*");
   config.EnableCors(cors);`

`// Other configurations`

`}`

***Controller*** or ***Action -*** If desired/required to place support at these levels (*this will overwrite global settings* - Action > Controller > Config). Above Controller or Action signature:

`[EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:[port #]", headers: "*", methods: "*")]`

**Note:** * are "wildcards", might want to put the domain making the request **ex:**(http://localhost:[*port #*])

Something that is very easy to miss/forget...

IN solution explorer, right-click api-project. In properties window **set 'Anonymous Authentication' to Enabled !!!**